# how do i use error provider in a radio button which is inside a group box?

Tags: c#

```
  if (rbMale.Checked == false && rbFemale.Checked == false)
        {
            flag = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
            groupBox1.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1, "Please Select the gender");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1,"");
        }
```

When I check one of the radio buttons. It still shows that red icon  Why is it showing that error icon. Please check the code and help me out. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your code is in the `FormClosing()` event because of the `e.Cancel` line? 
 If so, this code will only reset the error when the form is being closed...

To make the error clear as soon as a RadioButton is selected, you'd also have to wire up the `CheckedChanged()` events of both "rbMale" and "rbFemale" like so:

```
    private void rbMaleAndFemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbMale.Checked || rbFemale.Checked)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(groupBox1, "");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to move this validation to common method and trigger this on both `CheckBox's Click Events`,
where you need to update your errorProvider whenever you are checking / unchecking the checkboxes